# Optimizing a mysql date query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to optimize the following query that compares the `last_updated` value against a datetime. My basic query is:

```
SELECT Count(1) AS loopCount FROM main_iteminstance mi 
WHERE mi.last_updated >= '2018-04-12 07:25:23.000';
```

Doing an `explain` gives me:

[image]

And running the query takes about 8s even though the field is indexed. Is there a better way to do the above? There are about 10M rows here.

The table looks something like this (though has many more fields):

```
CREATE TABLE `main_iteminstance` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `last_updated` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `last_updated` (`last_updated`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=205421031 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Show `CREATE TABLE` please.

Comment: Daretime fields are very unfit indexing choices. Can’t you create a secondary date column through ETL in the same table? If so, index that column.

Comment: @bishop please see updated question.

Comment: @SouravA could I just convert it query-side to search by the date instead of datetime?

Comment: Thanks. Please also `SHOW INDEX`

Comment: If that loopCount value shown in the image is correct, then the statement saying "about 1k have a non-null timestamp" doesn't seem correct. It would seem there are at least 186K. Is that result from this table?

Comment: No, using scalar function is again going to be a problem.

Comment: How is the performance of this query - SELECT Count(1) AS loopCount FROM main_iteminstance mi 
WHERE mi.last_updated is not null;

Comment: its good idea SouravA, to filter not null in first then filter for WHERE mi.last_updated >= '2018-04-12 07:25:23.000'

Comment: @SouravA `not null` takes 10ms. `null` on the other hand takes about 15s.

Comment: @MarkWilkins yes you're right. Ignore the comment about the number of non-null values.

Comment: Thank you @janith1024 :)

Comment: @Sourava it's fine to index a datetime column

Comment: I say, it’s not wise to index on a datetime field because of the nature of datatype. There is a good chance(in an OLTP environment at least) that there is very high cardinality on this column which results in very high I/O while retreival or any DML statement - failure of the B-tree algo on which indexes are based and probably leading to scans being faster. I can’t think of a good enough reason to have an index on a datetime field. Of course, would like to hear your thoughts too - @strawberry

Comment: @SouravA how would you suggest performing this query in an optimal way in an OLTP environment then?

Comment: @SouravA or what would be a better field type or technique for doing the above?

Comment: Having a secondary date column and indexing it would be my preferred choice as in most cases that suffices(as in the case pit up by OP). Another technique is to trim the datetime to either start of hour or start of day and then indexing it. That way cardinality reduces significantly and the performance of index improves.

Comment: @SouravA thanks for the suggestion. How do OLAP environments usually handle this issue?

Comment: In insurance domain, where I work, most of user calculations do not require going into hours or minutes, but just days. There is a time dimension though(having hour grain) which is used in very special scenarios only and that too as an add-on to dimensions, not facts. Only in domains such as telecom, data might need capturing on hourly grains for analysis.

Comment: @SouravA it seems like this might be an issue thought with finance, where changes are much more time sensitive, etc. Do you know how they may handle that issue?

Comment: I am sorry, which issue? Do you mean datetime is required upto milliseconds grain? Or, that you wish to eliminate that and have it at sone other grain?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Count(1) AS loopCount FROM main_iteminstance mi 
WHERE mi.last_updated IS NOT NULL AND mi.last_updated >= '2018-04-12 07:25:23.000';
```

If this doesn’t work, add the results of the following query into a temp table and do the date time/date filtering on top of it:

```
SELECT Count(1) AS loopCount FROM main_iteminstance mi 
WHERE mi.last_updated IS NOT NULL
```